# Equivalent of For Loop in LINQ 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am new to LINQ.

`playerData` is a `list<DataAccess.Team>` and I want to initialize another list of `playerViewModelList` with the data from `playerData`.

I tried `foreach`.

```
 foreach (DataAccess.Team dataTeam in playerData)
 {
     playerViewModelList.Add(new PlayersViewModel
     {
         PicPath = dataTeam.Tied.ToString(),
         PlayerID = (int)dataTeam.ID,
         PlayerName = dataTeam.TeamName
     });
  }
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing using LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) is the equivalent in this case:

```
playerViewModelList = playerData.Select(dataTeam => new PlayersViewModel
                                        {
                                            PicPath = dataTeam.Tied.ToString(),
                                            PlayerID = (int)dataTeam.ID,
                                            PlayerName = dataTeam.TeamName
                                        }).ToList();
```

Of course, this assumes `playerViewModelList` is a `List<PlayersViewModel>` or something similar. If you can't overwrite `playerViewModelList`, just stick with the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
playerData.ForEach(d => playerViewModelList.Add(new PlayersViewModel {
    PicPath = d.Tied.ToString(),
    PlayerID = (int)d.ID,
    PlayerName = d.TeamName
}));
```

or

```
playerViewModelList.AddRange(playerData.Select(d => new PlayersViewModel {
    PicPath = d.Tied.ToString(),
    PlayerID = (int)d.ID,
    PlayerName = d.TeamName
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, as you have `List<>` on both sides:

```
  playerViewModelList = playerData.ConvertAll(dataTeam => new PlayersViewModel
  {
    PicPath = dataTeam.Tied.ToString(),
    PlayerID = (int)dataTeam.ID,
    PlayerName = dataTeam.TeamName
  });
```